# Joining 3 tables with unequal number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select *
from servrectrans
where servrectrans.refwo ='W3298301'
```

Query returns 2 records

```
select *
from wpservice
where wpservice.wonum ='W3298301'
```

Query returns only one record

Now when I run the below query, I am getting 2 rows returned

```
SELECT 
    wpservice.plusplineprice as PlanServicePrice,
    wpservice.linecost as PlanServiceCost,
    servrectrans.plusplineprice as ActualServicePrice,
    servrectrans.linecost as ActualServiceCost
FROM
((workorder     
inner join wpservice WITH (NOLOCK) on  wpservice.wonum = workorder.wonum  )
inner join servrectrans WITH (NOLOCK)  on servrectrans.refwo = workorder.wonum)    
where WORKORDER.WONUM = 'W3298301';
```

[image]

I think the second entries for PlanServicePrice and PLanServiceCost are incorrect? They should NULL.
Could this be fixed using a different type of join?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you provided sample data and desired results, then other people might be able to agree or disagree with you on whether the data is correct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I have provided a screenshot of the results returned

Comment: @GordonLinoff      may be I should re-phrase,  if table 1 has only one record, and table 2 has 2 records, how would the data be displayed when i join these 2 tables to a third table?

Comment: And please don't use images for data... use formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how standard joins work. They match rows from different tables according to the join condition you specify. The engine is doing it right.

Now, to get the result you want you can:

**1. Run queries separately and join in your app**

You can query both tables separately and then just join the result sets in your app. Not that complicated but your app will need to account for different numbers of rows from each side.

**2. Perform the join in the database**

You don't mention the database so I'll assume it's a modern one that supports `FULL OUTER JOIN`s (Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, SQL Server, etc.). If it doesn't, you'll need to tweak the query to simulate the full outer join:

You can do:

```
with
o as (
  select * from workorder where wonum = 'W3298301'
)
select 
  s.plusplineprice as PlanServicePrice,
  s.linecost as PlanServiceCost, 
  t.plusplineprice as ActualServicePrice, 
  t.linecost as ActualServiceCost 
from ( 
  select s.*, row_number() over(order by s.plusplineprice) as rn 
  from o join wpservice s on s.wonum = o.wonum 
) s 
full join ( 
  select t.*, row_number() over(order by t.plusplineprice) as rn 
  from o join servrectrans t on t.refwo = o.wonum 
) t on t.rn = s.rn
```

Comment: the query is returning

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 59
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Comment: Thanks!

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 65
The multi-part identifier "t.plusplineprice" could not be bound.

Comment: Another bug fixed, and its working as below

with
o as (
  select * from workorder where wonum = 'W3298301'
)
select
  s.plusplineprice as PlanServicePrice,
  s.linecost as PlanServiceCost,
  t.plusplineprice as ActualServicePrice,
  t.linecost as ActualServiceCost
from (
  select s.*, row_number() over(order by s.plusplineprice) as rn
  from o join wpservice s on s.wonum = o.wonum
) s
full join (
  select t.*, row_number() over(order by t.plusplineprice) as rn
  from o join servrectrans t on t.refwo = o.wonum
) t on t.rn = s.rn

Comment: Is there a way by which we could incorporate the above solution into the below query

Comment: select
sum(ISNULL(wplabor.plusplineprice,0)) AS PlanLaborPrice,sum(ISNULL(wpservice.plusplineprice,0)) AS PlanServicePrice ,sum(ISNULL(PLUSPWPGENBILL.LINEPRICE,0)) AS PlanFees,
sum(ISNULL(labtrans.plusplineprice,0))AS ActualLaborPrice,sum(ISNULL(servrectrans.plusplineprice,0))AS ActualServicePrice,sum(ISNULL(PLUSPGBTRANS.LINEPRICE,0)) AS ActualFees,
sum(ISNULL((wplabor.quantity*wplabor.laborhrs*wplabor.rate),0)) AS PlanLaborCost,sum(ISNULL(wpservice.linecost,0)) AS PlanServiceCost,

Comment: sum(ISNULL(labtrans.linecost,0))AS ActualLaborCost,sum(ISNULL(servrectrans.linecost,0))AS ActualServiceCost,
workorder.wonum as refwo

Comment: FROM
workorder 
left outer join  wplabor WITH (NOLOCK) on wplabor.wonum=workorder.wonum 
left outer join wpservice WITH (NOLOCK) on wpservice.wonum=workorder.wonum
left outer join PLUSPWPGENBILL WITH (NOLOCK) on PLUSPWPGENBILL.wonum=workorder.wonum
left outer join labtrans WITH (NOLOCK) on labtrans.refwo=workorder.wonum
left outer join servrectrans WITH (NOLOCK)  on servrectrans.refwo=workorder.wonum
left outer join PLUSPGBTRANS  WITH (NOLOCK) on PLUSPGBTRANS.wonum=workorder.wonum

Comment: where 
WORKORDER.ISTASK=0
and WORKORDER.HISTORYFLAG =0
and WORKORDER.STATUS not in ('DEFER','WINFO','WCAPPR')
and WORKORDER.PLUSPagreement = 'TC_BRAU_PM_01'
GROUP BY 
WORKORDER.WONUM